# JsonObject.GetNamedObject() order

Tags: c#, .net, json

I'm trying to read out JSON using the using `Windows.Data.Json`. But for some reason GetNamedObject() returns my objects in a very silly way..

This is my JSON:

```
{
   "schedule":{
      "schedule":{
         "Monday":{
            "1":{
               "class":"oo5",
               "classroom":"K53"
            },
            "2":{
               "class":"oo5",
               "classroom":"K53"
            }
         },
         "Tuesday":{
            "2":{
               "class":"biol6",
               "classroom":"S12"
            },
            "8":{
               "class":"loC",
               "classroom":"126"
            },
            "9":{
               "class":"loC",
               "classroom":"126"
            }
         },
         "Wednesday":{
            "3":{
               "class":"entlC",
               "classroom":"K51"
            }
         },
         "Thursday":{
            "3":{
               "class":"wisb3",
               "classroom":"S29"
            },
            "8":{
               "class":"inf8",
               "classroom":"S22"
            }
         },
         "Friday":{
            "1":{
               "name":"dhr. F. Lange de",
               "class":"schk1",
               "classroom":"S09"
            }
            "7":{
               "name":"mw. O. Beek ter",
               "class":"nat2",
               "classroom":"S10"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Note: this is a shortened version.

I'm trying to read out the days in the given order: "Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday".

I'm using the following C# code:

```
JsonObject JSON_OBJ_root;
JsonObject.TryParse(return_json, out JSON_OBJ_root);
JsonObject JSON_OBJ_schedule = JSON_OBJ_root.GetNamedObject("schedule");
JsonObject JSON_OBJ_days = JSON_OBJ_schedule.GetNamedObject("schedule"); //I think this is the problem
```

And when I use the debugger and lookup `JSON_OBJ_days`:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WX5I5.png

Translation:

```
Woensdag = Wednesday
Vrijdag = Friday
Donderdag = Thursday
Dinsdag = Tuesday
Maandag = Monday
```

So, for some reason GetNamedObject() returns its objects in a random order. This is just brain bending! Can anyone tell me why this is and how I could solve this problem?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object do not have an order in JSON. You should use an array where you want to save the order of the items.

Your JSON should be something like:

```
{
    "schedule": {
        "schedule": [
            {
                "name_day": "Monday",
                "schedule": [
                    {
                        "class": "oo5",
                        "classroom": "K53"
                    },
                    {
                        "class": "oo5",
                        "classroom": "K53"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name_day": "Tuesday",
                "schedule": [
                    {
                        "class": "oo5",
                        "classroom": "K53"
                    },
                    {
                        "class": "oo5",
                        "classroom": "K53"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Notice the [ instead of the {. "[" stands for an array where { is used when describing an object.

Comment: Thank you, I figured that the problem could be the order of an object that is not taken into account. Thanks for confirming that. I will mark this as my answer.